# Laravel show/load BLOB image from DB looks always like white cube/square

Tags: php, laravel, image, blob

I am using laravel and I use a MySQL DB.

I save images as blob into the database like this:

```
$path = $data->file;

$image = file_get_contents($path);

$base64 = base64_encode($image);

DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users_comments_files')->insert(
    ['comment_id' => $data->comment_id, 'filename' => 'TEST', 'date_added' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 'date_modified' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'filetype' => 'image/png', 'file' => $base64]
);
```

There is some data in the file column, so I assume it works.

Now I want to display the images in view, either in iframe or atm. create a URL.

**Here is the relevant part how I try to create/display the blob in view:**

```
return '<img data="data:' . $result->filetype . ';base64,
' . $result->file . '" type="' . $result->filetype . '" 
class="object-elem"></img>
```

I try to display them like this:

```
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users_comments_files')->where('id', $element_id)->first();

$object_type = 'object';
if (str_contains($result->filetype, 'image')) {
    $object_type = 'img';
}

return '<' . $object_type . ' data="data:' . $result->filetype . ';base64,
' . $result->file . '" type="' . $result->filetype . '" class="object-elem"></' . $object_type . '> 
<style>
    body {
        background-color:#3a3a3a;
    }
    .object-elem {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        min-width: 100px;
        min-height: 100px;
    }
</style>';
```

I dont get any errors, but the result is always a white square/cube:

[image]

Comment: why are you double encoding in Base64, `$base64 = base64_encode($image);` and `. base64_encode($result->file) .`

Comment: I am currently experimenting and trying out things a lot, I forgot to change this, but even if I encode only once, I still get the cube and no errors.

Comment: use the attribute `src`, not `data` in the `<img>` tag. Example: `src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA`

Comment: @N69S thanks! Seems to work for images. If you answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the double Base64 encode, and fill the attribute `src` not `data` in the `<img>` tag

```
<' . $object_type . ($object_type == 'img'?'src':'data') . ' 
    ="data:' . $result->filetype . ';base64, ' . $result->file . '" type="' . $result->filetype . '" class="object-elem">
</' . $object_type . '>
```